# Is it possible to debug Typescript in Visual Studio without IIS and ASP.NET debugging enabled?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, typescript

To successfully debug a Typescript project in Visual Studio 2013, I noticed that the web.config debugging flag needs to be set to "True". This led me to believe that debugging process in Visual Studio has a dependency on ASP.NET infrastructure (and IIS) because the configuration file contains System.Web tags.

I'm not talking about debugging using a browser. I'm aware of js.map files and how they are used. I want to be able to debug Typescript in Visual Studio 2013 without ASP.NET and IIS.

Comment: What is going to be executing the JavaScript, if not a browser?